# Identity loop - This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop

Tags: arrays, while-loop, dafny

please checkout my code below. The idea is just to add a constant (for example +1) to each array position. But dafny returns `BP5005: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.` for the forall condition.
It does not make much sense to me, because the loop body literally does exactly what we have defined in the invariant.

It is crucial that the asserts are valid in the Main method.

```java
method doNothing(arr: array<int>)
modifies arr;
ensures arr.Length == old(arr.Length);
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length ==> arr[i] == (old(arr[i]) + 1);
{
  var idx: int := 0;

  while(idx < arr.Length)
  decreases arr.Length - idx;
  invariant 0 <= idx <= arr.Length;
  // # ERROR: BP5005: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.Dafny VSCode
  invariant forall i :: 0 <= i < idx ==> arr[i] == (old(arr[i]) + 1);
  {
    arr[idx] := arr[idx] + 1;
    idx := idx + 1;
  }
}

method Main()
{
  var arr := new int[3];
  arr[0] := 1;
  arr[1] := 2;
  arr[2] := 3;

  doNothing(arr);

  assert(arr[0] == 2);
  assert(arr[1] == 3);
  assert(arr[2] == 4);
}
```

Does dafny somehow change the reference by assigning the same value???

Can somebody support me?

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop invariant speaks about the relation between `arr[i]` and `old(arr[i])` for indices in the range `0..idx`. But it doesn't say anything about that relation for indices in the range `idx..a.Length`. Therefore, there is no information about the value of `arr[idx] + 1` that the loop body assigns to `arr[idx]`.

Comment: hmm, but range 0..idx shoul right. And with `arr[idx] + 1` I would like to increase the old value by one. So this is index `idx`. Maybe you would provide some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after getting out of my rapid hole, please see the working solution:
thx to @Rustan

The crucial thing to notice is, that we do not need to explicit create an `invarient` for arr[idx], because this index is coveted by the invariant `0 <= j < idx` if we evaluate at the body end.

```java
method doNothing(arr: array<int>)
modifies arr;
ensures arr.Length == old(arr.Length);
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length ==> arr[i] == old(arr[i]) + 1;
{

  var idx: int := 0;

  while(idx < arr.Length)
  decreases arr.Length - idx;
  invariant 0 <= idx <= arr.Length;
  // #INFO: no need, it's covered by the invariant below, evaluating at the body end.
  // invariant arr[idx] == old(arr[idx]) + 1;
  invariant forall j : int :: 0 <= j < idx ==> arr[j] == old(arr[j]) + 1;
  invariant forall j : int :: idx <= j < arr.Length ==> arr[j] == old(arr[j]);
  {
    // Evaluate Inv before loop body
    arr[idx] := arr[idx] + 1;
    idx := idx + 1;
    // Evaluate Inv after loop body => uses already updated idx value
  }
}
// neglect Main method
```